# how to add jssor transition builder into exisiting slider?

Tags: slider, slideshow, transition, jssor

How can I add jssor transition into my slider?
I used the Jssor code like this:

```
<script src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<sc...>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});
<sc...>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/

This above code is working well, but now I'm gonna use this following  Transition Code:

```
{$Duration:1500,x:0.2,y:-0.1,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Outside:true,$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}}
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

Where in this following code can I add this transition?

```
<sc...>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});
</sc...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could find it. Here is the answer:

```
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
    //Define an array of slideshow transition code
    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    {$Duration:1500,x:0.2,y:-0.1,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Outside:true,$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}}
    ];
    // And you can add more transitions to the array. 
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            }
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
};
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html